# Hide element after fade out using only CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a one pager that shows one page at a time and that uses animation when transitioning from one page to the next. It works like this:

1. The user clicks on a button
2. An ajax call is done and while waiting for the response the page fades out (opacity: 0)
3. If the server does not respond within 500 msec after the fade out finishes a spinner fades in and stays there until the ajax call finishes
4. When receiving the response the spinner is faded out and the new page fades in.

I currently use a CSS 3 transition animation on the opacity of the page. This issue is however that during the time the spinner is visible the user can still interact with the (invisible) form of the page that just faded out (it's not gone, it's just invisible using opacity).

So I would like to have a CSS only solution that sets the page to visibility: hidden at the end of the transition (I cannot use display: none). What would be the way to go here?

Comment: What about wrapping the spinner element with a 100% width and height transparent div?

Comment: That would indeed prevent clicking on the elements, but it would not block tabbing to the form elements.

Comment: Then use the JS to disable the form elements

Comment: That would work, but I'm looking for a CSS only solution.

Comment: [`-moz-user-focus:ignore;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus) is the closest thing I found that describes this… but of course that’s not a viable option.

Comment: You can't prevent a user from interacting with an element just with CSS alone. And you're obviously already using JS, so I don't really see the big deal of disabling the form elements with JS. However I know for at least Chrome and FF (can't vouch for other browsers) when you decrease the opacity and highlight text or otherwise interact with the elements, the highlight also has decreased opacity. So that might be an option depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish/prevent.

Comment: These all looks like patch work to me. It's bound to go wrong in some cases.

Comment: It's no more "patch work" than your ajax call or fading the element out or the spinner in...

Comment: Setting `tabindex="-1"` might work.

Comment: What I mean with patch work is that it patches an issue with the spinner overlaying the form to prevent people from accessing it. It does not solve the issue itself: the elements still being editable. It's better to somehow signal to the browser that the form is no longer available. Using visibility: hidden or display: none. This way the browser wil block all possible inputs automatically.

Comment: Form elements are not editable if you disable them.

Comment: I honestly think CSS is the wrong approach here. An overlay `<div>` to prevent clicks and a `function noTab(e){e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();}; window.addEventListener('keydown',noTab);` and afterwards `window.removeEventListener('keydown',noTab);` to prevent tabbing (and any typing) is the _safest and most reliable_ way to get this done (if JS is enabled, ha ha).

Comment: OK, I thought of another way (that also uses JS too, but in a different way). You're obviously using JS since you're using ajax, so can you explain a bit more clearly why it's ok to use it for ajax, but not for disabling the elements, and if there is anything else you *don't* want to use JS for so that I can see if this solution would work or not?

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for thinking along with me on this. The no JS is more a "can it be done" type of thing. CSS animations are way faster than JS based ones and I'd rather prevent having to do all kinds of timing sensitive stuff in JS. I created a working example based on a keyframe idea of one of the answers. See my own answer for the details. If you see any issues with this approach feel free to comment on my own answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the answer of @Rev I created a proof of concept. It works nicely (see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8201h5q/3/)).

When you add the class 'fadeOut' to the div it'll fade out and end with a visibility: hidden state. Remove the class and it fades in again. You can tell that it is really hidden by hovering your mouse over it: if hidden it will no longer give the "text selection" mouse pointer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page">
    Lorem ipsum etc etc etc. 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .page {
      -moz-animation-name: fadeIn;
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
      -ms-animation-name: fadeIn;
      animation-name: fadeIn;
      -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
      -ms-animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    }

    .page.fadeOut {
      -moz-animation-name: fadeOut;
      -webkit-animation-name: fadeOut;
      -ms-animation-name: fadeOut;
      animation-name: fadeOut;
    }

    @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; } 100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }}
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; } 100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }}
    @-ms-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; } 100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }}
    @-keyframes fadeIn { 0% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; } 100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }}

    @-moz-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }  100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }} 
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }  100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }} 
    @-ms-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; } 100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }} 
    @-keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; } 100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;  }}
```

Some additional remarks:

1. If you have child elements in the `.page` element that have explicitly `visibility: visible` set on them then they will react to interaction via mouse. This is because hey are not hidden just invisible due to the opacity: 0. The twitter bootstrap `collapse` plugin does this for instance. You can solve this by setting their visibility to `inherit` instead of `visible`. This will cause them to only be visible if their parent is. For instance the collapse plugin can be made to behave using this additional css:

   .page .collapse {
     visibility: inherit;
   }
2. This does not work in IE 9 and below.
3. You need the browser prefixes as seen in my code to make this work. I tested this without the prefixes and both the latest chrome (42) and firefox (37) did not work without them. This is ugly but can be made easier by using something like SASS with Compass. Here's the same code using that approach:

**SASS with Compass**

```
.page { 
  @include animation(fadeIn 1s ease-in-out forwards); 
}

.page.fadeOut { 
  @include animation-name(fadeOut); 
}

@include keyframes(fadeIn) {
  0% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
  100% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }
}

@include keyframes(fadeOut) {
  0% { opacity: 1; visibility: visible; }  
  100% { opacity: 0; visibility: hidden; }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the 1% and 99% frames? It seems to work for me without them.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I though that the visibility would swap immediately when the animation started, but it doesn't. That would have resulted in a switching on and off without any fading. But I was wrong, so I'll remove them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not completely JS-only, but when you start the fade animation, also add a class to the form container with the following CSS:

```
.disableMouse * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will disable clicks (but it won't disable scrolling).  Works in all current browsers, but IE support was only added in version 11.  So this may not be the best option for you if you need to support IE10 and earlier.

Comment: Good thinking. I had never heard of `mouse-evends` before. However it only stops just that: mouse events. You can still tab to it using the keyboard and alter the value. See http://jsfiddle.net/fpjpghLd/

Comment: I need it to be CSS only. Moreover there are issues with this like the prevent comment points out.

Comment: yeah... would be nice if there were a keyboard equivalent for `pointer-events`.  I don't see a way to do this without script to disable the form elements

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure I can't be done with CSS alone. You could look in to the JavaScript's `transitionend`.

You could look in to CSS animations rather than transitions as well. I know you can't transition `visibility: hidden;` but you might be able to set up an animation key frame at 100% to do this.

Comment: The `transitionend` event is new to me and looks pretty cool. It is however JS and I'm looking for a CSS only solution. The keyframe is also interesting. I'll look into that.

Comment: Yea I haven't used it in s few years but it's pretty nice. I'd look in to animations more but I'm on mobile, so good luck 

Comment: I created a working example based on your keyframe idea. See my own answer for the details. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

If your only intent is to disable interaction, you could use `pointer-events: none` (IE11+) on your page, or have a floating blocker over the top, like;

```
.page.loading {
    position: relative;
}
.page.loading:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: white;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```