# How do I fade a container to the left when I click on an item in the container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to make an effect that is executed by clicking on an item within the container, container slide to right/left and fade, after the content is faded it needs do be display hide to make place for new content.

The future header will be placed outside the container thus the header do not fade. Nothing i tried seem to work. Anybody any suggestions for this problem?

I will be implementing the effect on my website [www.bartmulder.nl/beta1.0](http://www.bartmulder.nl/beta1.0) so when you click on a photo the container whit all the photos will fade and slide before display none

```js
// change .box1 to .container and you will see the effect that i am looking for
$('.box1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("containerWerk").style.display = "none";
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.box img {
  margin: 0px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container.clicked {
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerWerk" class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
```

Comment: `$(element).animate` - [here's a useful link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for API docs regarding this.

Comment: This question and answer can get you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30064932/hide-element-after-fade-out-using-only-css

Comment: @escapesequence thanks i will look in to this, looks helpfull

Comment: try this: https://jsbin.com/zusufapeki/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the jQuery / JavaScript way of accomplishing this too...
Simply just call `animate` on the element and specify what kind of animation, speed, and completion function (optional).

For the example below I am passing a JSON object to specify what actions to accomplish with the animation (which I removed from CSS), then after the animation it will trigger the element to not be displayed any longer.

```js
// change .box1 to .container and you will see the effect that i am looking for
$('.box').on('click', function() {
  $(this).animate({
     opacity: 0,
     marginLeft: -100
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

```css
.box img {
  margin: 0px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerWerk" class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must apply the class 'clicked' in the parent element '.container', not in the 'this', so use jQuery parent to access the parent element '.container' to add the clicked class in the correct element.

```js
// change .box1 to .container and you will see the effect that i am looking for
$('.box1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.container').toggleClass('clicked');

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("containerWerk").style.display = "none";
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left:0;
  position: relative;
}

.box img {
  margin: 0px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container.clicked {
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerWerk" class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
```

If you want just the image go to other side

```js
// change .box1 to .container and you will see the effect that i am looking for
$('.box').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left:0;
  position: relative;
}

.box img {
  margin: 0px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left:0;
  position: relative;
}

.box.clicked {
  margin-left: -100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="containerWerk" class="container">
  <div class="box box1">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="100" />
  </div>
```